# Windows 10 Default Programs don't stick

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, default-settings

I can't for the life of me get my default program selections to take on Windows 10. For example, I use the Default Programs app to set my browser to Chrome which works temporarily. But after a week or so the setting reverts back to either Edge or empty in the settings app.

The same thing is happening with extension mappings. For example, I have PNG and jpg images mapped to Paint.net. Immediately after changing the mapping paint.net pops up as expected. After a while the image file default prompts to select a viewer instead of opening the file.

This was originally a clean install of Windows 10 Professional about a half a year ago. It's never worked in all this time.

Any idea why the settings are not sticking?

Could this have something to do with interaction between applications running as Administrator and running as default user account and the settings getting corrupted between the two account settings?

Comment: This is due to a bug in Feb Cumulative Update. See the report at http://www.infoworld.com/article/3032751/microsoft-windows/windows-10-forced-update-kb-3135173-changes-browser-and-other-defaults.html and the registry fix http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-resetting-file-associations/

Comment: @w32sh You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: Done. Converted into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in Windows 10 Feb Cumulative Update. See the report at http://www.infoworld.com/article/3032751/microsoft-windows/windows-10-forced-update-kb-3135173-changes-browser-and-other-defaults.html

This is a wide-spread issue, and the only fix is the registry edit available at http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-resetting-file-associations

It stops Modern apps from taking over the associations (and the screen refresh everytime a reset is made)